# Constructing a std:map only once within a method

Tags: c++, mfc, stdmap

I have this static method:

```
CString COutlookCalendarSettingsDlg::GetExitCodeAsString(DWORD dwExitCode)
{
    using OutlookExitCodesMap = std::map<DWORD, CString>;

    OutlookExitCodesMap mapExitCodes;

    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(1, _T("NoError")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-1, _T("CommandLineArguments")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-2, _T("BuildingCalendarList")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-3, _T("CalendarEventsPathNullEmpty")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-4, _T("CalendarEventsPathNotFound")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-5, _T("ModeSwitchNotSpecified")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-6, _T("ModeSwitchInvalid")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-7, _T("AddEventsMWB")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-8, _T("AddEventsSRR")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-9, _T("SignOut")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-10, _T("ReadMWBData")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-11, _T("ReadSRRData")));

    return mapExitCodes[dwExitCode];
}
```

Now, I know that I could turn this into a global variable in the class an get the `GetExitCodeAsString` method to just return from this global variable.

But how can I keep the map defined within the method, but, only construct it once? I don't need to keep re-building it. So, the first time it is called it would construct it and subsequent times it would just return the value.

Can this be done?

Comment: I would use a simple `switch(dwExitCode)` here which would be equally or even more efficient than your map solution. As most of the case values are consecutive the compiler can build an efficient jump table.

Comment: @zett42 So you think a `switch` statement, each with a `return _T("xxxxx");` node is going to be the best resolution?

Comment: @zett42 What about compared to the other suggestion in the answer that uses `struct`? I am using that right now.

Comment: _a switch statement, each with a return _T("xxxxx");_ - that's what I had in mind. The suggestion of using a struct is still more complicated than a `switch` statement, so I would prefer the `switch`.

Comment: @zett42 I accepted the initial answer but I supplied your idea as a second. Which is simpler to look at to the eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple but ugly:

```
CString COutlookCalendarSettingsDlg::GetExitCodeAsString(DWORD dwExitCode)
{
  using OutlookExitCodesMap = std::map<DWORD, CString>;

  static OutlookExitCodesMap mapExitCodes;

  if (mapExitCodes.size()==0)
  {
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(1, _T("NoError")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-1, _T("CommandLineArguments")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-2, _T("BuildingCalendarList")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-3, _T("CalendarEventsPathNullEmpty")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-4, _T("CalendarEventsPathNotFound")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-5, _T("ModeSwitchNotSpecified")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-6, _T("ModeSwitchInvalid")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-7, _T("AddEventsMWB")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-8, _T("AddEventsSRR")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-9, _T("SignOut")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-10, _T("ReadMWBData")));
    mapExitCodes.insert(std::pair<DWORD, CString>(-11, _T("ReadSRRData")));
  }
  return mapExitCodes[dwExitCode];
}
```

This code is not safe for multi threading. Also if there is an unknown exitcode the map grows. No need for this...

But why use a map for such simple code. Much simpler and not using any heap, even any construction:

```
CString COutlookCalendarSettingsDlg::GetExitCodeAsString(DWORD dwExitCode)
{
  using OutlookExitCodesMap = std::map<DWORD, CString>;


  static const struct { 
    int     dwCode;
    LPCTSTR pszText;
  } 
  aMap[] = 
  {
    1, _T("NoError"),
    -1, _T("CommandLineArguments"),
    -2, _T("BuildingCalendarList"),
    -3, _T("CalendarEventsPathNullEmpty"),
    -4, _T("CalendarEventsPathNotFound"),
    -5, _T("ModeSwitchNotSpecified"),
    -6, _T("ModeSwitchInvalid"),
    -7, _T("AddEventsMWB"),
    -8, _T("AddEventsSRR"),
    -9, _T("SignOut"),
    -10, _T("ReadMWBData"),
    -11, _T("ReadSRRData"),
  };
  for (const auto &data : aMap)
  {
    if (static_cast<DWORD>(data.dwCode)==dwExitCode)
       return data.pszText;
  }

  return CString();
}
```

Code may have typos... I just wrote it from scratch

Comment: Thanks for this. I simplified the `for` loop to `for (auto & i : aMap)`. And I changed the return value to `_T("")`. I see no other errors. So the `using` keyword is obsolete now. I tried to give the `struct` a name of `OutlookExitCode` but then the `aMap` complained about a missing `;`.

Comment: Yes, using the new for syntax is easier. If using a name for the structure, you have to separate declaration and definition.

Comment: Ah, so what you have provided is a special coding style then. No worries. I have not done it like this before. Thanks.

Comment: I do get a compile warning: *warning C4838: conversion from 'int' to 'DWORD' requires a narrowing conversion*. This is for the numerical constants.

Comment: Just changed my answer. Also made the elements const. So they will recide in the code block and will reduce the program size. Where do you get this error?

Comment: If I prefix each number with `(DWORD)` it is OK. But can't we use a special letter to inform the compile the literal numbers are DWORD? Hover over the 1, -1, -2 etc and the compiler thinks they are `int`. Unless I cast.

Comment: A negative number is never a DWORD. Use 0xFFFFFFFF for -1. Or use int in the struct and use a cast in the compare.Changed my answer.

Comment: OK, thanks. I have also provided another answer, based on the comments provided to me about using a `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution based on the comments provided to my question:

```
CString COutlookCalendarSettingsDlg::GetExitCodeAsString(DWORD dwExitCode)
{
    switch (dwExitCode)
    {
    case 1: return _T("NoError");
    case -1: return _T("CommandLineArguments");
    case -2: return _T("BuildingCalendarList");
    case -3: return _T("CalendarEventsPathNullEmpty");
    case -4: return _T("CalendarEventsPathNotFound");
    case -5: return _T("ModeSwitchNotSpecified");
    case -6: return _T("ModeSwitchInvalid");
    case -7: return _T("AddEventsMWB");
    case -8: return _T("AddEventsSRR");
    case -9: return _T("SignOut");
    case -10: return _T("ReadMWBData");
    case -11: return _T("ReadSRRData");
    }

return CString();
```

}

Comment: Yes, I think this is the cleanest code and won't be less efficient than the other solutions for reasons I already wrote in the question comments.